# display of slider in chrome using foundation 3

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, zurb-foundation

I am building a site using foundation 3 and the native orbit slider.

so far so good... but the slider info does not appear in the correct place in chrome.

ok, easy fix i hear you say...apply chrome specific styles.  Good, I like the idea except that messes with safiri, which renders the page fine.

The html:

```
<div id="featured">
    <div>
        <img src="images/slider/ironman-txt.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="featuredInfo">
        <h3>IRON MAN</h3>
        <hr />
        <p>When Tony Stark’s world is torn apart by a formidable terrorist called the Mandarin, Stark starts an odyssey of rebuilding and retribution.</p>
            <ul class="featuredActions">
            <li><a href="#">Watch Trailer</a></li>
            <li>-<a href="#">15 PG Rating</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Book Seats</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The css (scss):

```
#featured {
    background-color: $white;
    max-height: 400px;
    .featuredInfo {
    float: right;
    padding: 0 1em;
    max-width: 25.5em;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 10; 
    h3 {
        padding: 0.5em 0 0.1em 0;
        margin: 0;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    hr {
        margin: 7px 0;
        border-color: $txtColor;
        height: 2px;
        border-width: 1px;
    }
}
```

a live link:

http://madmantis.co.uk/sites/schwack/

I know that if I add position: relative; and top: -400px; the featured info div will move to the correct position in chrome but obviously knock out the other browsers.

I am a little troubled as using foundation, I can not see what's wrong...

Comment: Docs(http://foundation.zurb.com/old-docs/f3/orbit.php) say that when adding text to orbit, you need to specify the ratio of your orbit panel.

Comment: Also, you should consider using foundation 4

Comment: I like the idea of specifying an aspect ratio... no joy with this bug unfortunately. 

Client specifically wants foundation 3.  I wonder if there is a way to target chrome and not safari (i.e. not using webkit)??

Comment: There are probably nicer libraries, but you can try [this](http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/) library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a neat little solution...

to differentiate chrome from safari (and other android browsers) the webkit css selector cannot be used.

this tiny script sorted it out:

http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/